# Installing Firefox add-on globally without extracting the .xpi archive

Tags: linux, debian, firefox

Since the great `-install-global-extension` option was removed in Gecko 1.9.2 (for no obvious reason, as usual), copying the extension (as `root`) to `/usr/lib/iceweasel/extensions/<appid>` is now the only way out to avoid the cumbersome Windows-ish "File-Open..." procedure (which requires that `Firefox`/ `Iceweasel` is running, too)
But I want to install my extension(s) without launching the browser first.
So this is the steps I did (or better, I was forced to do)

- have `myapp.xpi` ready on my storage media
- extract `install.rdf` with `unzip` and `cat` it to retrieve app ID

Lastly, I do a

```
sudo unzip /media/wherever/myapp.xpi -d /usr/lib/iceweasel/extensions/<appid>
```

The `-d` option will specify the directory where to extract to (if it does not exist yet, the directory will be created).
OK, **that method actually works**. But I thought this is a bit stone-age, perhaps?

I *actually* expected to only copy the `*.xpi` to the `extensions` directory and let `Firefox`/`Iceweasel` unpack it by itself. However, this does not work.

I tried all of the following four variants to no avail:

- copy `myapp.xpi` to `/usr/lib/iceweasel/extensions` as-is
- copy `myapp.xpi` to `/usr/lib/iceweasel/extensions/<appid>/` as-is
- copy `myapp.xpi` to `/usr/lib/iceweasel/extensions` and rename it to  `{appid}.xpi`
- copy `myapp.xpi` to `/usr/lib/iceweasel/extensions/<appid>/` and rename it to `{appid}.xpi`

However, neither of said methods made the extension show up in Add-On Manager.

Maybe the unpacking is mandatory under Linux?
I also consulted the official "documentation", which, TBH, is abysmal. It only gives an example for Mac OS X, but not for Linux. Plus,the wording is fairly incomprehensible. Check yourself:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Installing_extensions

So how am I supposed to perform this installation under Linux (Debian here) *without* unpacking the extension by hand?